# VSCode: execute command when focus on terminal view?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks, vscode-snippets

I've set "ctrl + end" to execute this multicommand sequence,
[image]

[image]

When I focus on the terminal view, executing the command will output some characters in the terminal,not execute the actual command, how can I execute the command even in I'm focus on terminal view?

[image]

Comment: @user In the workbench, using the multi-command will result "focus on git commit view", but when Im focus on terminal, using the command will output some characters in terminal, I want to execute the command like when its on the workbench, and "focus on git commit view".

Comment: @user "send keybindings to the shell" is not checked

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. My Bash shell just does nothing when I try to reproduce it, and the SCM panel is not opened, etc. What shell is in the integrated terminal you're using? Apologies for the first part of my first comment. I didn't see the first part of the list of your commands when I first wrote it. Still, it stands that you should provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use terminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell setting:

```
    "terminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell": [
        "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    ]
```